# How many mutex and cond variable?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am wokring on pthread pool and there will be five separate thread and one queue. All the five threads are competing to get a job from the queue and I know the basic idea that I need to do lock/unlock and wait/signal.

But I am not sure how many mutex and cond variable I should have. Right now I have only one mutex and cond variable and all five thread will use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on @Ivan's solution...

Instead of a mutex + condition variable, you can use a counting semaphore + atomic operations to create a very efficient queue.

```
semaphore dequeue_sem = 0;
semaphore enqueue_sem = 37; // or however large you want to bound your queue
```

Enqueue operation is just:

```
wait_for(enqueue_sem)
atomic_add_to_queue(element)
signal(dequeue_sem)
```

Dequeue operation is:

```
wait_for(dequeue_sem)
element = atomic_remove_from_queue()
signal(enqueue_sem)
```

The "atomic_add_to_queue" and "atomic_remove_from_queue" are typicaly implemented using atomic compare&exchange in a tight loop.

In addition to its symmetry, this formulation bounds the maximum size of the queue; if a thread calls enqueue() on a full queue, it will block.  This is almost certainly what you want for any queue in a multi-threaded environment.  (Your computer has finite memory; consuming it without bound should be avoided when possible.)

If you do stick with a mutex and condition variables, you want two conditions, one for enqueue to wait on (and deque to signal) and one for the other way around.  The conditions mean "queue not full" and "queue not empty", respectively, and the enqueue/dequeue code is similarly symmetric.

Comment: Well, I don't think the solution is simpler actually. But description is definitely more readable/detailed. +1

Answer (score 3):

One mutex and at least one condition variable.

One mutex because there is one 'thing' (i.e. piece of memory) to synchronize access to: the shared state between all workers and the thread pushing the work.

One condition variable per, well, condition that one or more threads need to wait on. At the very least you need one condition variable for waiting on new jobs, the condition here being: "is there more stuff to do?" (or the converse: "is the work queue empty?").

---

A somewhat more substantive answer would be that there is a one-to-many relationship between a mutex and associated condition variables, and a one-to-one relationship between shared states and mutexes. From what you've told us and since you're learning, I recommend using only one shared state for your design. When or if you need more that one state I'd recommend looking for some higher level concepts (e.g. channels, futures/promises) to build up on abstraction.

In any case, don't use the same condition variable with different mutexes.

Comment: +1. And you probably want another condition for "the queue is not full".  Unbounded data structures + asynchrony = tempting fate

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could do stealing work from queue without locking at all via Interlocked operations if you organize it as stack/linked list (it will require semaphore instead of condition variable to prevent problem described in comments to this answer).

Pseudo-code is like that:

1. candidate = head.
2. if (candidate == null) wait_for_semaphore;
3. if (candidate == InterlockedCompareExchange(head, candidate->next, candidate)) perform_work(candidate->data);
4. else goto 1;

Of course, adding work to queue should be also via InterlockedCompareExchange in this case and signaling the semaphore.

Comment: Incorrect.  If multiple threads check `candidate == null`, then multiple other threads signal the condition, only one of the waiters will see the signal and wake up.  You _must_ use a mutex in conjunction with condition variables, period.

Comment: Agreed with problem existance. Not agreed (at least for now) with impossibility. If to replace condition variable with counting semaphore initialized with count of threads?

Comment: Sure, for a queue you can use a semaphore instead of mutex+condition.  You could also use a pipe or a socket or any number of different primitives.  But that was not the question...  (Fix your answer to be correct and I will remove my downvote)

Comment: Well the question was about efficient implementation of classic producer/consumer scenario. And there IS queue in the question. I think that Interlocked operations without blocking on loaded scenario with semaphore will have more throughput than mutex/condition variable implementation. If the question was pure academic - to determine minimal number of synch primitives of certain type - then you're correct :)

Comment: OK, but your answer as written now is _wrong_.  Fix it to suggest using a semaphore plus interlocked operations as an alternative, if you like.  But please do not leave a buggy answer, especially to this kind of question :-)

Comment: Yep, it was my fault. I think it is fixed now.

Comment: Downvote removed, and +1 for the good idea.  (You can similarly use another semaphore to limit the size of the queue, which is also a good idea...)

Comment: Actually, the code is simpler than you provide.  The semaphore (call it S1) should be initialized to zero.  Its purpose is to count the number of elements in the queue.  Another semaphore S2 can then be used to count the "empty space" in the queue; initialize it to the queue size.  Then enqueue/dequeue become extremely symmetric operations.  Dequeue is just "wait for S1" then "interlocked remove".  Enqueue is just "wait for S2" then "interlocked add".

Comment: Well, what is exactly simpler? Symmetrization doesn't relieve you from possibility of interlocked fail if between 1st and 3rd steps head was changed by another interlocked. So, your "interlocked add" and "interlocked remove" would still require that cycle in 4th step.

Comment: No, it does not.  Here, let me put it in my own answer.  If you decide to change yours to match, I will remove mine.

Comment: Btw, after some thinking. Solution with deque won't work as there will be bizarre corner cases with removing last element. To be precise one could force such solution to work, but complexity and error-proneness... it's not worth the time

Comment: I have written up my version of this approach in a separate answer.

Comment: I thought of removing my answer... but discussion here with pit-falls could be valuable for someone. So will leave as it is.